# Convert the array values into json object using Jolt Transform in Apache NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to convert the array values into the Individual JSON object using Jolt transform NiFi.

**Input:**

```json
{
  "headers": {
    "query": "NA",
    "param": "false"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "SEQ_NUM": [
        162,
        162,
        162,
        162,
        162,
        162,
        162,
        162
      ]
    },
    {
      "SEQ_NUM": [
        162,
        162,
        162,
        162,
        162,
        162,
        162,
        162
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Jolt Spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "": {
          "SEQ_NUM": {
            "": {
              "@": "[&1].SEQ_NUM"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jolt spec is wrong. You should add `*` to empty keys in your jolt. So you can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "SEQ_NUM": {
            "*": {
              "@": "[&1].SEQ_NUM"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

If you want to prevent duplicate values in the output, You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "0": {
          "SEQ_NUM": {
            "*": {
              "@": "[&1].SEQ_NUM"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]